# <%@LANGUAGE="JAVASCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%> shows up the top of my webpage

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I'm not a coder so I'm using Dreamweaver CS5.5 to create my website.
I've used a (html 5) Template to create the pages and have noticed that the first line of code is showing at the top of the pages when rendered within ALL browsers.

It is the first line of code right at the top:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="JAVASCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
```

This line does NOT appear in 'design view' or 'live view' within Dreamweaver but DOES show in the 'code view'. If I'm in 'code view' and then press the 'Live Code' button it dis-appears from the top of the code. Then re-appears when I turn it back off - So I presume this is what's supposed to happen when rendered except for some reason it is showing up.

Is it important and will it affect anything if i deleted it?
I'm presuming it is there for a reason so any help in hiding it when rendered would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't be in an html page. That tag is for a server to interpret. Seems like a remnant from an ASP page?

Comment: Hi, That was fast...   well the template is saved with a .dwt.asp extension. i think i just realized the problem. turns out i had selected javascript template type when creating the new document instead of html. Sorry for the bother and Thanks for the quick response which made me look again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it important and will it affect anything if i deleted it?

Yes, but not in HTML code. It's server-side code. It won't affect anything if you deleted it.